# ANTLR: Policy Broken on Whitespace Processing

Tags: java, antlr

Okay, I often feel like the dumbest person to ever use ANTLR based on the number of questions I've already posted, but here I am asking for assistance again.

I ended up trying to rewrite an existing policy to simplify it, only to have the "simplified" one decide to bomb out on whitespaces, which are supposed to be sent to the HIDDEN channel (skip() didn't work either). It might just be out-of-order Lexer tokens, but I'm stumped (maybe I don't have a good understanding of how to specify order).

Anyhow, here's the entire (somewhat sanitized) policy:

```
grammar ValidatingPolicy;

options {
  language = Java;
    backtrack = true; 
}

// package and imports for the parser
@parser::header {
package org.jason.manager.impl;

import org.jason.manager.RecognitionRuntimeException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
}

// package and imports for the lexer
@lexer::header {
package org.jason.manager.impl;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
}

// member functions and fields for the parser
@parser::members {

 private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidatingPolicyParser.class);
 @Override
 protected Object recoverFromMismatchedToken(IntStream input, int ttype, BitSet follow) throws RecognitionException {
   throw new MismatchedTokenException(ttype, input);
 }

  @Override
 public Object recoverFromMismatchedSet(IntStream input, RecognitionException e, BitSet follow) throws RecognitionException {
   throw e;
 }

 @Override
 public String getErrorMessage(RecognitionException e, String[] tokenNames) {
  // wrap in a runtime exception to escape ANTLR's dungeon
  throw new RecognitionRuntimeException(e);
 }
}

// member functions and fields for the lexer
@lexer::members {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidatingPolicyLexer.class);
}

// validate a group of SHOW constructs
showGroup
  : show+ EOF
  ;

// validate a construct WITHOUT show (MINQ, MOS, etc)
noShow
  : simpleIfStatement+ EOF
  ;

// validate a SHOW construct (COMP or ELIG validation)
show
  : SHOW STRING FOR simpleIfStatement+
  ;

// handle an if statement
simpleIfStatement
  // basic if statement
  : IF chainedOperation THEN operationGroup (ELSE operationGroup)? ENDIF
  // if statement with recursive if statement in THEN or ELSE block
  | IF chainedOperation THEN simpleIfStatement (ELSE simpleIfStatement)? ENDIF
  | operationGroup
  ;

// aggregate multiple operations. When evaluated, there is an implicit AND
// when there are multiple groups
operationGroup
  : chainedOperation+
  ;

// chain an operation together optionally with AND/OR
chainedOperation
  @init {
    log.info("Entered chainedOperation");
  }
  : operation (AND operation | OR operation)*
  ;

// aggregate into a single rule that can be referenced up the chain
operation
  @init {
    log.info("Entered operation");
  }
  // legal operation
  : (booleanLogical | stringLogical | integerLogical | dateLogical | datePeriodLogical)
  ;

// LOGICAL OPERATIONS
// Logical operators do not have a pass through, but may have limits
// on which particular operators can be used

// compare DATE/DATE_FIELD to DATE/DATE_FIELD
dateLogical
  @init {
    log.info("Entered dateLogical");
  }
  : dateOp (EQ|NE|LT|LE|GT|GE) dateOp
  ;

// compare DATE_PERIOD/DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT/DATE_PERIOD_FIELD
datePeriodLogical
  @init {
    log.info("Entered datePeriodLogical");
  }
  : datePeriodOp (EQ|NE|LT|LE|GT|GE) datePeriodOp
  ;

// compare INTEGER_FIELD/INTEGER
integerLogical
  @init {
    log.info("Entered integerLogical");
  }
  : integerOp (EQ|NE|LT|LE|GT|GE) integerOp
  ;

// compare BOOLEAN_FIELD/BOOLEAN_CONSTANT
booleanLogical
  : booleanOp (EQ|NE) booleanOp
  ;

// compare STRING_FIELD/STRING
stringLogical
  : stringOp (EQ|NE|LT|LE|GT|GE) stringOp
  {
    System.out.println("stringLogical: matched rule 1");
  }
  ;

dateOp
  @init {
    log.info("Entered dateOp");
  }
  // pass through if no math op needs to be performed
  : DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT
  // match a legal math op
  | DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT ((PLUS|MINUS) DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT|DATE_PERIOD_FIELD|DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT (' ' DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)*)*
  ;

datePeriodOp
  // pass through if no math op needs to be performed
  : DATE_PERIOD_FIELD|DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT
  // match a legal math op
  | DATE_PERIOD_FIELD ((PLUS|MINUS) DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT|DATE_PERIOD_FIELD|DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT+)*
  ;

integerOp
  @init {
    log.info("Entered integerOp");
  }
  // pass through if no math op needs to be performed
  : INTEGER_FIELD | INTEGER
  // match a legal math op
  | INTEGER_FIELD (PLUS|MINUS INTEGER_FIELD|INTEGER)*
  ;

// booleanOp, stringOp, and waiverOp don't do anything since + and - ops are not
// supported for them
booleanOp
  : BOOLEAN_FIELD | BOOLEAN_CONSTANT
  ;

stringOp
  : STRING_FIELD | STRING
  ;

// these items are not directly referenced by parser rules, so they
// can be fragments

fragment DIGIT: ('0'..'9');
fragment DATE: ;
fragment DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT: DIGIT+ ' '+ (YEAR | MONTH | WEEK | DAY);
YEAR: ('YEAR'|'YEARS');
MONTH: ('MONTH'|'MONTHS');
WEEK: ('WEEK'|'WEEKS');
DAY: ('DAY'|'DAYS');

DATE_FIELD:('DOB'|'TEST_DATE');
DATE_PERIOD_FIELD:('EMPLOYMENT_PERIOD');
BOOLEAN_FIELD:('CERTIFIED');
INTEGER_FIELD:('AGE'|'OPTION');
STRING_FIELD:('STATE'|'UF_USERID'|'USER_LEVEL');

// various tokens can't be fragments since they are directly referenced by parser rules
COMMENT_START: ';';
BOOLEAN_CONSTANT: ('TRUE'|'FALSE'|'"Y"'|'"N"');
DATE_CONSTANT:('TODAY'|'YESTERDAY'|'TOMMOROW');
SHOW: 'SHOW';
FOR: 'FOR';
IF: 'IF';
THEN: 'THEN';
ELSE: 'ELSE';
ENDIF: 'ENDIF';
AND: 'AND';
OR: 'OR';
EQ: '=';
NE: '<>';
LT: '<';
LE: '<=';
GT: '>';
GE: '>=';
NOT: 'NOT';
HAS: 'HAS';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';

// Commented ifs seem to take more than one line, even if comments are
// only supposed to be a single line
COMMENTED_IF: COMMENT_START WS* IF (options {greedy=false;} : .)* ENDIF '\r\n'
{
  log.info("Lexer: matched COMMENTED IF" + getText());
  $channel=HIDDEN;
  //skip();
};

// Handle an empty comment such as "; "
EMPTY_COMMENT: COMMENT_START WS* '\r\n'
{
  log.info("Lexer: matched EMPTY_COMMENT: " + getText());
  $channel=HIDDEN;
};

// Handle a single-line comment. Policies often end with a comment, so be ready for it
SINGLE_COMMENT: COMMENT_START ~('\r'|'\n')*  (('\r\n')+| EOF)
{
  log.info("Lexer: matched SINGLE_COMMENT: " + getText());
  $channel=HIDDEN;
};

INTEGER
  // Bart Kiers on SO helped me with this one, basically handle a date period such as
  // 4 WEEKS, 1 YEAR 6 MONTHS 2 WEEKS 8 DAYS, etc
 : (DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)=> DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT ((' '+ DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)=> ' '+ DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)*
   {
      // manually switch the type from INTEGER to DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT
     $type=DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT;
     log.info("Matched DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT: " + getText());
   }
 | DIGIT+
   {
      // match a 6-digit or 8-digit date format (20120101 or 201201)
     if ($text.matches("(19|20|21)[0-9]{2}[0-1]\\d{3}") || $text.matches("(19|20|21)\\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])")) {
      log.info("Matched DATE pattern: " + getText());
       $type = DATE;
     } else {
      log.info("Matched INTEGER: " + getText());
     }
   }   
 ;

STRING
  : '"' ID  (' ' ID)* '"'
  ;

ID: ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'|DIGIT|','|'!'|'?'|':')+;

WS: (' '+|'\r'|'\n'|'\t') 
{
  //skip();
  $channel=HIDDEN;
};
```

A "show" construct should look something like this:

```
SHOW "DOES NOT MEET AGE REQUIREMENTS FOR EMPLOYMENT" FOR
  AGE < 18

SHOW "TOO YOUNG FOR CERTIFICATION IN KY" FOR
   IF STATE="KY" THEN AGE > 21 ENDIF
```

It works when I remove spaces, such as around the String, or from around the operator, etc.

Also, if anyone sees any other stupidities in the grammar, I'd be glad to hear them.

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Your lexer is matching spaces in an implicit, unnamed lexer rule. This lexer rule is referenced in parser rule `dateOp`:

```
dateOp
  //...
  // pass through if no math op needs to be performed
  : DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT
  // match a legal math op
  | DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT 
     ((PLUS|MINUS) DATE_FIELD|DATE|DATE_CONSTANT|DATE_PERIOD_FIELD|DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT 
       (' ' DATE_PERIOD_CONSTANT)* //<--- ' ' becomes a new lexer rule
     )*
  ;
```

It behaves like a normal lexer rule, so with this input:

```
SHOW "DOES NOT MEET AGE REQUIREMENTS FOR EMPLOYMENT" FOR
  AGE < 18
```

The lexer produces these tokens:

```
[SHOW : SHOW] [' ' :  ] [STRING : "DOES NOT MEET AGE REQUIREMENTS FOR EMPLOYMENT"] 
[' ' :  ] [FOR : FOR] [INTEGER_FIELD : AGE] [' ' :  ] [LT : <] [' ' :  ] 
[INTEGER : 18]
```

Note the `[' ' :  ]` tokens. These are the implicit lexer rule at work. The parser isn't expecting these tokens outside of the `dateOp` rule, so parsing gags.

After removing the `' '` from parser rule `dateOp`, the input above produces the following tokens, as expected:

```
[SHOW : SHOW] [STRING : "DOES NOT MEET AGE REQUIREMENTS FOR EMPLOYMENT"] 
[FOR : FOR] [INTEGER_FIELD : AGE] [LT : <]
[INTEGER : 18]
```

I don't know whether removing the `' '` from `dateOp` is acceptable in your grammar or not. If the space needs to be tested for explicitly, consider rewriting what you can to move the whitespace test down into the lexer. Alternatively, the parser could look ahead to see if the next token is a hidden WS one. For starters, though, I recommend just cleaning up `dateOp` as best as possible and see where things land.